# Как несколько строк перевести в массив?

Tags: массивы, winforms, строки, c++-cli

У меня есть TextBox, не однострочный, у меня, например, там

```
25 16 32
16 81 23
61 13 51
```

Как я могу перевести все это в одномерный `int` массив? Делаю все через C++/CLI

Answer (score 0):

разбить Ваш TextBox с помощью `string.split()` - возвратит массив строк. И потом все значения массива перевести в int.